# Is there a way to add a configurable modal/lighbox/pop-up to a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

Problem:

I manage a series of websites for clients that are all in the same industry. During certain times of the year (ie. Christmas, New Years, Summer, etc), we want to push certain promotions or specials on the sites. Right now when this happens, I have to go to each client's website (some wordpress, some straight html, some grav, some dnn...) and change some code to reflect the promotion.

Desired solution:

I would like to go into a tool/ui, configure some settings like the text, an image and a start/end date and have a pop up dialog be displayed on the website. For bonus points, I'd love to be able to build/schedule these ahead of time and just let them run. I use some tools like Drip that do something similar (displaying a modal) for sign up forms but haven't found anything that quite fits what I'm trying to do.

Ideas so far:

All of our sites have tag manager so I think there may be a way to do it using it. I would likely not be able to run things on a schedule or get an easy way to configure the modals but at least it would get me out of having to go to each site and do something different. I could copy/paste the html for the modal for each container, turn the tag on/off and update the markup when needed. Does that sound reasonable or a terrible idea? It feels like there should be something that does this already but I cant find anything.

Anyways, if someone has done something similar or if there are any tools/libraries I could buy I'd really appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible by using the Custom HTML Tag..

Comment: Can you guide me on how?

Comment: Then search on changing your DOM with javascript, so your tag shows the modal, then you could use a trigger to show it.